# Not able to get output from camel routing

Tags: rest, cxf, apache-camel, cxfrs

I have defined a camel context with a camel route and I am having below code.

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:9090/camelcxfdemo/rest/cxf/camelRouter?matchOnUriPrefix=true").
    to("jetty:http://localhost:9090/camelcxfdemo/rest/cxf/getPersonData?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
    .to("jetty:http://localhost:9090/camelcxfdemo/rest/cxf/processPersonData?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
    .to("log:output");
```

All the three urls shown above are Rest services which takes some post xml and return xml response.

I want my camel router to start working when /camelRouter is called and its output should go to /getPersonData url and the output of /getPersonData go to /processPersonData. And to user I should finally display the output of /processPersonData.

So each url is dependent on it's previous urls output.

But the problem is when I invoke /camelRouter url, I always get /camelRouter response, not the final output. The output is not routing from one service to other.

So is there is any probelm in my code? Hoping for some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the Jetty component can be used as either a producer or consumer but not both as you appear to be attempting to use it.